# Is there a limit on how many entries you can have for a pricing table?

Tags: interaction-design, tables, grid, pricing

I would like to use a pricing table for my application. For reference, my understanding of a pricing table looks like [these images](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=pricing%20table&newwindow=1&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=703&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid-da-oaPRAhXmIsAKHQ9LC-8Q_AUIBigB).

My possible problem is that there will probably be alot of data entries (> 20), so is a pricing table no longer an option because of the number of data entries?

Answer (score 1):

**Don't make the user think**. The user will spend a limited time in the app so:

- Give him what he is looking for without overwhelming him
- Catch his attention with an easy and quick to understand list

There is no limit as this depends on the case, but look at your scenario and think: **if you were going to spend only a few seconds to understand all that information would all the choices you are displaying be too many?**

If you need to make the user choose between 20 different sets of options then try to make the decision in steps. For example first a selection between a reduced number of options and in a second step a second selection of a more specific option (from the previous selected set).